# jquery.html(string) auto adds sub elements. Sounds like a bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I don't understand what happens here.

If if type in the console

```
$('h1.page-title').html('<ul></ul>')
```

it outputs

```
<h1 class="page-title">
    <ul></ul>
</h1>
```

but if I type in the console

```
$('h1.page-title').html('<ul class="ul-content"></ul>')
```

it outputs

```
<h1 class="page-title">
  <ul class="ul-content">
    <ul></ul>
  </ul>
</h1>
```

why is the extra "ul" node added?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ornnw5m3/ Are you sure you didn't write `html('<ul class="ul-content"><ul>')` -- missing the `/` in `</ul>`?

Comment: Nope I too cant reproduce it either

Comment: go to http://api.jquery.com/ and do the example I gave in the console. I've got the bug for jquery 1.11.X

Comment: I don't have the bug in jsFiddle, but I have it in my backbone app, and on the jQuery website itself. Headache ahead.

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome 45. This is on api.jquery.com. http://imgur.com/R8pR17p

Comment: Works also fine today for me on Chrome 45, on api.jquery.com... quite despair on this